# Amazon AWS S3 SDK for iOS drops connection (Error -1005)

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, region

When running the AWSiOSDemoTVM project, the async S3 demo code will start uploading data, but the connection will be dropped after a couple of seconds.

> AWSiOSDemoTVM: didFailWithError : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."UserInfo=0xb54e850
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/asyncDemoKey,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/asyncDemoKey,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0xb5527f0 "The network connection was lost."}

Small uploads without using the asynchronous delegate will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't set the correct endpoint for the bucket. The default endpoint only works for US buckets.

In AmazonClientManager.m, add the correct endpoint for your bucket region.

```
    s3  = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials];
    s3.endpoint = @"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
```

A list of regional endpoints for S3 and other AWS services can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Comment: Just curious, will your app be published on App Store or for internal use?