# Trying to upload an image to AWS S3 bucket error -1005

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, xcode9

I'm trying to upload an image on S3 with no success. It always sends me a -1005 error network connection was lost.

> 2017-10-11 00:24:15.843988+0200 OOL[18620:712534] Task .<4> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
>   2017-10-11 00:24:15.844396+0200 OOL[18620:712782] Task .<4> finished with error - code: -1005
>   Upload image failed with error The network connection was lost.

After some research i found out that there could be an issue with the client-server time difference and that the difference doesn't have to be more than 15 min. And if this information is true how can i solve it?

This is my `AppDelegate.swift`

```
let awsCredentialsKeys = Helper.shared.getAWSCredentialKeys() //0 is the access key. 1 is the secret key.
let staticCredentials = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: awsCredentialsKeys.0 , secretKey: awsCredentialsKeys.1)
let configration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUWest2, credentialsProvider: staticCredentials)

AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configration
```

This is my upload request code:

```
///Save image to AWS S3 Bucket
func uploadImageToS3(filePath:URL, bucketName: String, imageKeyName: String) -> String? {

    var s3URL = String()
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.bucket = bucketName
    uploadRequest?.key = imageKeyName
    uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    uploadRequest?.body = filePath
    uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.unknown
    uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {
        (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print(totalBytesSent)
            print(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        })
    }

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread()) { (task:AWSTask) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain, let code = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code){
                switch code {
                case .cancelled, .paused:
                        break
                default:
                    print("Upload image failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Upload image failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }
        if task.result != nil {
            s3URL = "https://\(Helper.shared.getS3BucketURL())/\(Helper.shared.getAWSBucketName())/\(imageKeyName)"
            print("Uploaded to: \(s3URL)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    return s3URL

}
```

Comment: Any chance you are uploading to S3 in region A, but the bucket is actually in a region B? And, just in case it's clock skew (which I doubt), see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/clock-skew-fix/.

Comment: @jarmod The region is correct i even added the endpoint too in the AppDelegate now according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971707/amazon-aws-s3-sdk-for-ios-drops-connection-error-1005 but no use same error. I even tried running it synchronously but same error.  Yes i checked out this link an hour ago.

Comment: Call me crazy, but "the network connection was lost" sounds like it *should* indicate connectivity problems.

Comment: @jarmod & Michael-sqlbot thanks guys for the help i just had an issue in the file path. I wasn’t generating a correct file path url that is why i had this error.